# showing custom field values in Wocommerce my-address view section

Tags: woocommerce, account

i added custom fields to myaddress edit section in my account page in woocommerce.but i am not seeing it in my address displaying section.how can i show it there also.There only company ,first name, lastname ,billing address 1, billing address 2,state city and country is displaying.how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', function( 
           $args, $customer_id, $name ){
           // the phone is saved as billing_phone and shipping_phone
               $args['area'] = get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_area', true );
               return $args;
             }, 10, 3 ); 


              add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', function( $formats ) 
 {
              foreach ( $formats as $key => &$format ) {
               // put a break and then the phone after each format.
                $format .= "\n{area}";
                   }
             return $formats;
             } );
```

Comment: This was what i  was looking